# Validating submission of animated GIF to OpenCV imread() function

Tags: c++, validation, image-processing, opencv, animated-gif

I have an OpenCV C++ program that reads in user submitted images (using imread() function) and processes them. I need to validate that the image is not an animated GIF before I start processing, as OpenCV generates errors while trying to process animated GIF.

Is there a way I can differentiate between static GIF and animated GIF so I can throw an error when the user is submitting an animated GIF?